# Can't correctly read .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

When importing a .csv, I saved the result as a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
csv_dataframe= pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(r'filepath.csv', delimiter=';', encoding='iso-8859-1', decimal=',', low_memory=False))
```

However, when I call a specific column that has numbers and letters, it ignores some of the characters or adds others. For example,  in column 'A', there are elements similar to this:

```
'ABC123456789'
'123456789'
'1234567'
```

and when I call:

```
csv_dataframe['A']
```

The results are:

```
'ABC123456789'
'1234567342'
'3456475'
```

So, some of the values are correct but, in others, it changes the values, adding or removing elements. In some cases it even alters their length.

Is there some form of changing the way that other programs read .csv files in the .csv file, for example? That is, is there an option in the .csv file that masks values that isn't noticeable when openning it? Or, did I make any mistake when calling the file/functions, please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: without seeing the .csv file, it's going to be hard to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'pd.DataFrame()'

pd.read_csv already creates a dataframe

This should work:

```
csv_dataframe= pd.read_csv(r'filepath.csv', delimiter=';', encoding='iso-8859-1', decimal=',', low_memory=False)
```

It might fix your issue, other than that, I'm willing to bet the issue is in the CSV.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I suspect that as well, that is why I asked if it is possible to use some kind of function in the csv. Do you know some?

Comment: Not without seeing the csv, like Patrick Conwell said. Sorry, bud.